# Missing the Rails 2.3.11 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.11 rails`,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I am having a problem with my rails install on ubuntu 11.04 and not sure what the problem is ...i just installed rails and passenger and rvm on production and all seems ok but for some reason i keep getting

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.11 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.11 rails`,
```

Here is the [link](http://umaniweb.com/)

when i am on the application and i do

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activerecord (2.3.11)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.11)
bundler (1.0.21)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.9.2.2)
```

so it doesnt make sense what is going on and why its telling me that i dont have rails installed...any ideas on what im doing wrong

Here is my rvm info

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

gem install -v=2.3.11 rails
Fetching: rake-0.9.2.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: rails-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.11
Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.11
Successfully installed rack-1.1.2
Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.11
Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.11
Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.11
Successfully installed rails-2.3.11
8 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...



=> ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]


rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.8.7-p334 (found in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334)
   global
=> ticket_mule
```

UPDATE environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION


Rails::Initializer.run do |config|


  # Specify gems that this application depends on and have them installed with rake gems:install
  # config.gem "bj"
  # config.gem "hpricot", :version => '0.6', :source => "http://code.whytheluckystiff.net"
  # config.gem "sqlite3-ruby", :lib => "sqlite3"
  # config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"
  config.gem 'will_paginate'
  config.gem 'authlogic'
  config.gem 'searchlogic'
  config.gem 'paperclip'
  config.gem 'prawn'
  config.gem 'populator'
  config.gem 'faker'
```

Comment: there is no gemfile....because this is a older rails application

Comment: it could be that 2.3.11 is getting installedf against 1.8.7 and you are actually using 1.9.2 which doesn't have the gem or something like that.

Comment: which gemset do you want

Comment: oh right, please show your environment.rb file.

Comment: rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.8.7-p334 (found in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334)
   global
=> ticket_mule

Comment: Try to read an error message: `Missing the Rails 2.3.11 gem. Please gem install -v=2.3.11 rails, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.`

Comment: updated my question with envirnment.rb

Comment: @OlexandrSkrypnyk - what are you talking about...i read the message....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your passenger is not using the RVM environment at all. For that to work out of the box, you need to

- have your app run under the `ubuntu` user (which it doesn't do by default, it uses the webserver user `www-data` by default) and setting proper defaults so that the correct ruby and gemset is used RVM, or to
- set up full passenger integration for RVM. See http://beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/ for more info about that.

Note that passenger can only use exactly one ruby at a time. While you can use different gemsets on the same ruby in a single passenger instance (e.g. fpr multiple applications), you can not switch between rubies.

Comment: How do i do this have your app run under the ubuntu user (which it doesn't do by default, it uses the webserver user www-data by default) and setting proper defaults so that the correct ruby and gemset is used RVM

Comment: Passenger has a feature called [user switching](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching) (see there). You also need to configure passenger to use your rvm ruby with `PassengerRuby` and friends. If you install passenger with your chosen ruby, the `passenger-install-apache2` script will output the correct configuration to use.

Answer (score 1):

That's rather famous problem linked with `rack`. Please see [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gem-dependency) for possible solution your issue. There is [one more article](http://rubyflow.ru/items/1168) about it, but unfortunately it was written on russian.